# How to InitialContext.lookup instance of EJB by Class<?>

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am trying to create an EJB class using it's class type. My function gets this class type as parameter. This class has it's own dependencies and i want those dependencies to be created as well.

```
addToUploadQueue(Class<? extends ICallback> callbackClazz)
```

how can i create an ejb instance of this class?

Edit: i am uploading videos to youtube on a ManagedExecutorService thread.This is a generic module. i want this to run on every project. Http requests call my function, i create another thread and return immediately. When upload finishes i need to inform this callback function to update statusses of those videos on db (or do whatever they want).

Comment: What you're trying to do here will be messy and complicated. If you describe the problem you're trying to solve here you might be given some better alternatives.

Comment: i am uploading videos to youtube on a ManagedExecutorService thread. this is a generic module, so i need to inform my caller about my job is finished. So it can update status of those videos on db

Comment: Which version of Java EE are you targeting?

Comment: i am using java ee 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the extra information that you have provided, it looks a little like you're trying to reinvent the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Fortunately, Java EE 6 and newer provides us with a CDI framework that implements this for us.

Adam Bien shows an example at [JAVA EE 6 OBSERVER PATTERN / EVENTS WITH CDI (JSR-299/JSR-330) AND EJB 3.1](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_ee_6_observer_with).

Comment: thank you, not for just solving my problem but giving me a different perspective on my problems. there is a lot to know. one needs to at least have some hint for what is what to guess potential solutions to problems.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get a ejb instance using the lookup method, you can do something like that

```
addToUploadQueue(Class<? extends ICallback> callbackClazz) {
  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
  MyEjb myEjb = (MyEjb)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/" + callbackClazz.getName());
}
```

Comment: i tried that. but i always get NamingException. do i need to add that ejb's name somewhere on beans.xml? by the way i am using wildfly with weld